# Js: chrome storage get content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-storage

I want to extract the content of dataflowid in the chrome storage but i get the output on the photo down bellow

```
var a = chrome.storage.sync.get(['dataflowid']);
console.log(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to log the value in the callback function (second parameter to `get()`) per the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/):

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(['dataflowid'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.dataflowid);
});
```

Comment: is there any method that i can print the result.dataflowid outside the function?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: i need the data in another function

Comment: Call the function from the callback, and pass it as a parameter?

Comment: do you have maybe a example im new in js